# Can we send transactions to specific node?

Tags: mining, full-node

If we are run a full node on our server for mining purposes, then can we send transactions to our node for mining purposes in order to save our transaction fees?

Comment: You mean, you want to mine your own transactions?

Comment: Yes. Or does every transaction need to be broadcasted to all miners and then a random miner will pick it up and mine it?

Comment: @goodvibration Thanks . Yes it does answer my question